# Textgeometry facing user when camera turns

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I am creating this 3d graph that represents a network of people. The nodes in the network are the names of people and between them lines are drawn whi9ch represents a connection. The purpose of this network is that people can turn it around and look through it to see what their network looks like, however, when I turn the camera around the network, the 3d text that I creat3ed with textgeometry is stuck to the same position and unformtunately therefore unreadable for the user when they want to look at the network from a different side. I know that this question has been asked several times before and I have read most of the answers on here, but I still cannot get it to work.
The problem that I encounter mostly is that when I try to do something like this:

```
nodeRenderer.lookAt(camera.position);
```

I get a problem that the camera is not defined. The camera is added to the scene, however this happens in a different .js document. This is where the scene gets created and the camera gets added (/ngraph.three/index.js):

```
var THREE = require('./lib/three');

module.exports = function (graph, settings) {
  var merge = require('ngraph.merge');
  settings = merge(settings, {
    interactive: true
  });

  var beforeFrameRender;
  var isStable = false;
  var disposed = false;
  var layout = createLayout(settings);
  var renderer = createRenderer(settings);
  var camera = createCamera(settings);
  var scene = settings.scene || new THREE.Scene();

  (...)

  function renderNode(nodeId) {
     nodeRenderer(nodeUI[nodeId]);
  }

  (...)

 function initNode(node) {
     var ui = nodeUIBuilder(node);
     if (!ui) return;
     // augment it with position data:
     ui.pos = layout.getNodePosition(node.id);
     // and store for subsequent use:
     nodeUI[node.id] = ui;

     scene.add(ui);
 }

 (...)

 function createCamera(settings) {
     if (settings.camera) {
       return settings.camera;
     }
     var container = renderer.domElement;
     var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.1, 3000);
     camera.position.z = 400;

     return camera;
 }
```

And this is where the nodes get created (ngraph.three/lib/defaults.js):

```
var THREE = require('./three');

module.exports.createNodeUI = createNodeUI;
module.exports.createLinkUI = createLinkUI;
module.exports.nodeRenderer = nodeRenderer;
module.exports.linkRenderer = linkRenderer;

function createNodeUI(node) {
  var nodeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00cccc, shading: THREE.FlatShading } ), // front
     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) // side
  ] );

  var nodeGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( node.data, { size: 5, height: 2, curveSegments: 6, font: "helvetiker", weight: "normal", style: "normal" });
  var nodeDirection = new THREE.Quaternion (THREE.Camera.Quaternion);

  return new THREE.Mesh(nodeGeometry, nodeMaterial);
}

function createLinkUI(link) {

  var linkGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  linkGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  linkGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

  var linkMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00cccc });
  return new THREE.Line(linkGeometry, linkMaterial);
}

(...)

function nodeRenderer(node) {
    node.position.x = node.pos.x;
    node.position.y = node.pos.y;
    node.position.z = node.pos.z;
}

(...)
```

I tried *ui.quaternion = camera.quaternion;* in /ngraph.three/index.js, but this didn't do anything, and I've tried *nodeUI.lookAt(camera.position);* but this gave an error: *TypeError: nodeUI.lookAt is not a function*.

PS: I'm using Three.js Rev. 68, Ngraph and node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess since a lot of code is missing  but your `createNodeUI` returns a `THREE.Mesh` which is a subclass of `Object3D`  which has the function `.lookAt(vector)`  to align its  local z-axis to the given vector.

And you said you receive this Error : `TypeError: nodeUI.lookAt is not a function`  that looks like you re trying to call `.lookAt` of the array and not of the node itself.

so try `nodeUI[node.id].lookAt(camera.position)`

Comment: Perfect! And so simple! Thanks so much ^^